# Use of the commutator to reduce the degree of a permutation

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

I've found the following claim [here (page 4, in the proof of thm 1.1)](http://www.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/papers/04soda.diam.pdf).

Set $A$ the support of a permutation $\tau$ in $S_n$, with $\deg\tau=|A|=k$.
Given a permutation $\pi$ in $S_n$ such that
$$|A\cap A^\pi| \le 1+(k^2/n)(1+\delta)$$
we have that
$$\deg[\tau,\tau^\pi]\le 3+3(k^2/n)(1+\delta)$$

How can I prove this?

(notation:

- the support of a permutation is the set of elements it moves
- $A^\pi$ is the set $\{a^\pi\bigm|a\in A\}$ and $a^\pi$ is the element obtained by applying $\pi$ to $a$
- $\tau^\pi$ is the conjugate of $\tau$ by $\pi$: $\tau^\pi = \pi^{-1}\tau\pi$
- $[\tau,\tau^\pi]$ is the commutator of these two elements: $[\tau,\tau^\pi]=(\tau^{-1}\pi^{-1}\tau^{-1}\pi)(\tau\pi^{-1}\tau\pi)$ )

---

Edit: this question is a generalization of [Commutator is a 3-cycle if...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227335/commutator-is-a-3-cycle-if)

Comment: Did you mean $\deg[\tau,\tau^\pi]$ in the second inequality (the one you want to prove)?

Comment: You might find it easier to use the same notation as in the paper, where $\tau^\pi=\pi^{-1}\tau\pi$ and $[\tau,\pi] = \tau^{-1}\pi^{-1}\tau\pi$. The general idea is that only elements of $U \cup U^{\tau} \cup U^{\tau^\pi}$ can lie in the support of $[\tau,\tau^\pi]$, where $U=A \cap A^\pi$.

Comment: @Arthur yes, I corrected the typo

Comment: @DerekHolt yeah ok, I changed the notation. Can you be more explicit why the elements could only belong to $U\cup U^\tau\cup U^{\tau^\pi}$?

Comment: It's a routine check! For example, points in $A \setminus(U \cup U^\tau)$ are moved by $\tau^{-1}$ to a point not in $A^\pi$, so image is fixed by $\tau^{-\pi}$ then moved back where it came from by $\tau$ and left alone by $\tau^\pi$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I'm maybe slow but I still don't get it… :-)

Comment: @DerekHolt I still don't understand your answer… It seems trivial as you write it but I think I miss something obvious

Comment: @JackSchmidt I know that mathematicians like to give hints instead of answers but could you please give an explicit answer? I'm dealing with this question for a long time and, even if the answer is trivial, I still don't get it. :-)

Comment: @lvaneesbeeck please see my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE 01/19/2014 : This answer which initially contained a
long comment has now been updated to a full answer.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

To expand on Derek Hold’s comments (which are only partially correct)

Let $U=A\cap A^{\pi}$, $\beta=\pi^{-1}\tau\pi$ and $\gamma=[\tau,\beta]=\tau^{-1}\pi^{-1}\tau^{-1}\pi\tau\pi^{-1}\tau\pi$.
Let $x$ be an integer between $1$ and $n$.

**Lemma 1.** (1) If $x\not\in A$ and $\pi^{-1}\tau\pi x\not\in A$, then $\gamma x=x$.

(2) If $\pi x\not\in A$ and $\pi\tau x\not\in A$, then $\gamma x=x$.

**Proof of lemma 1.** (1) Under those hypotheses we have $\tau^{i}(x)=x$
and $\tau^{i}(\pi^{-1}\tau\pi x)=\pi^{-1}\tau\pi x$ for every integer $i$, and hence

$$
\gamma x=\tau^{-1}\pi^{-1}\tau^{-1}\pi\tau\big(\pi^{-1}\tau\pi x\big)=
\tau^{-1}\pi^{-1}\tau^{-1}\pi\big(\pi^{-1}\tau\pi x\big)=\tau^{-1} x=x
$$

(2) Under those hypotheses we have $\tau^{i}(\pi x)=\pi x$
and $\tau^{i}(\pi\tau x)=\pi\tau x$ for every integer $i$, and hence

$$
\gamma x=\tau^{-1}\pi^{-1}\tau^{-1}\pi\tau\pi^{-1}\tau\big(\pi x\big)=
\tau^{-1}\pi^{-1}\tau^{-1}\pi\tau\pi^{-1}\big(\pi x\big)=
\tau^{-1}\pi^{-1}\tau^{-1}\big(\pi\tau x\big)=
\tau^{-1}\pi^{-1}\big(\pi\tau x\big) =x. 
$$

**Lemma 2.**  If $x$ satisfies neither of the hypotheses in (1) or (2) of the above
lemma, then one of the following three must hold : $\pi x\in U,\pi\tau x\in U,\tau\pi x\in U$.

**Proof of lemma 2** If $x$ does not satisfy the hypotheses of (1), then either
$x\in A$ (case 1) or $\pi^{-1}\tau\pi x \in A$ (case 2).
If $x$ does not satisfy the hypotheses of (2), then either
$\pi x\in A$ (case 3) or $\pi\tau x \in A$ (case 4).

Combining the two disjunctions, we have four cases :

Case 1,3 : $x\in A,\pi x\in A$. Then $\pi x\in U$.

Case 1,4 : $x\in A,\pi\tau x\in A$. Then $\pi\tau x\in U$.

Case 2,3 : $ \pi^{-1}\tau\pi x\in A,\pi x\in A$. Then $\tau\pi x\in U$.

Case 2,4 : $\pi^{-1}\tau\pi x\in A,\pi\tau x\in A$. Here two sub-cases must be
distinguished. If $x\in A$, then $\pi x\in U$. If $x\not\in A$, then $\tau\pi x \in U$.

This concludes the proof of lemma 2.

Finally, combining lemma 1 with lemma 2 we obtain $|{\sf supp}(\gamma)| \leq 3|U|$ as
wished.

Comment: Great answer! I need to write it down to the smallest details for myself to fully understand it but I think it deserves the bounty ;-)